# Loading 2 DLLs with the same name but different contents

Tags: c++, windows, oracle, dll

I have a Windows `C++` application that builds into an excel plugin. My application links against the oracle 12 client, via OCCI `(https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/oci.html`).

At runtime, the program will delay load oracle `dll’s` such as `ocil.dll, oraons.dll, OraOCIEI12.dll.`
Note that the dll’s are set to delay-load, because they are stored on a file server (not set in the user's windows `PATH` variable), and the first thing the program does, is to set this location.

We have users that combine our excel plugin with their own `VBA` code that uses an `oracle ODBC driver`. The problem is that none of our users have `oracle 12 client` installed on their own machines. They run oracle 11 client instead, and are not allowd to upgrade.

Oracle doesn’t have version dependencies in their names; both oracle 11 and 12 clients are dependent on `oci.dll, oraons.dll`, etc. The dll’s are version dependent, their names are not.

There are two kind of crashes:

1. First the user calls something via our library, and then via the external VBA code. What happens is that the oracle 12 dll’s are loaded first. Our library runs fine, but the VBA code crashes since it is trying to use the oracle 12 libraries.
2. First the user calls the VBA code, and then our library. The VBA code loads the oracle 11 dll’s and runs fine, but our library crashes.

Our application links to the SDK libraries downloaded from: 
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html 
(instantclient-sdk-nt-12.2.0.1.0.zip)
Our application has to link to oracle 12, since we compile with Visual Studio 2017 and the MSCV 14.14 compiler.

Can I somehow make it work that I load both oracle clients?

I looked at the oracle header files, and nothing in there specifies the name of the dll’s that need loading. Our application links to `oci.lib`, and in there I can see multiple occurances of `“OCI.dll”`. Perhaps I could replace them with `“OCI12.dll”`?

I also found this page:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3eaa07f-7f92-4693-8aa1-b8fee0b92d2f/cannot-load-2-dlls-with-same-name-but-different-versions

I tried it. When I do an explicit `LoadLibraryA("oci.dll")`, I can see in the debugger that I am loading the one that i set with the manifest. However, when I then make an actual function call that uses oracle, it is loading the ohter OCI.dll (on our file server), togehter with 3 other oracle dlls: `oraocci12d.dll, OraOCIEi12,dll and oraons.dll`. Maybe this has something to do with how oracle loads dlls?

For completeness, the user does something like this in his VBA code:

```
Dim cnnPointer As ADODB.Connection
cnnPointer.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Oracle in 112};" _
                            & "DBQ=" & Me.txtMiljoe.Text & ";" _
                            & "UID=" & Me.txtUser.Text & ";" _
                            & "PWD=" & Me.txtPassword.Text & ";"
```

Thanks in advance. 
Nele

Comment: Which ODBC driver is used? The Microsoft driver or the Oracle driver?

Comment: Hi Wernfried, Thanks for asking. I've added this info to the problem statement.

Comment: Maybe try (just for testing) the Microsoft driver `{Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}` - this works independently from Oracle version. Actually, it is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle?view=sql-server-2017) and should not be used. Perhaps you can install the ODBC drivers version 12.

Comment: Hi Wernfried, installing oracle driver 12 with the clients would solve all their issues (and then they would have to update their VBA code to pick the right client). The problem is that the clients don't have admin rights over their machines and oracle 12 is not on the list of software programs that can be installed via the IT department.

Comment: IMHO forget about OCCI and replace it by any available open-source C++ wrapper. Pure OCI has very stable ABI and it will work for you regardless of version you use.

Comment: @ibre5041 can you recommend a wrapper?